# Multi-message anti-SPAM filter in SpamAssassin

Tags: spam, spamassassin, spam-filter

My vendor's database has been stolen and I started to receive spam messages in a huge amount. It is being sent by spambots / spam scripts, so sender and recipient email addresses are always fake. The only common thing is that these messages are:

- Always delivered in three copies (to all three addresses of mine)
- Always with exactly the same title and content

Since there is a very little chance that any legitimate sender will send three exactly the same copies of the same message, I was wondering, if there is any way filter out all messages that appears in Inbox that exists there in exactly three copies?

Comment: Wouldnt bayesian matching pick up the rest if you just pass a few identified ones to sa-learn? E.g. piping `doveadm fetch ... | sort | uniq -c | grep "^3 " | cut -f2 | xargs -r .. doveadm copy tempfolder ... && sa-learn --spam temfolder/`

Comment: @anx Thanks for your suggestion. I'll try to implement it. If there will be any valuable results, I'll surely post about them here, in an updated answer. But given the fact that each "three messages pack" is always different in any possible aspect (auto-generated sender, different content, auto-generated recipient) then I assume that no bayesian matching is able to cherry-pick each such "three messages pack" next time it comes to my Inbox.